# How to get phone number from contacts to my SMS app

Tags: android

I created an SMS app that is a default on my NEXUS 5 (KIT KAT). When I open my contacts and click on the message icon it opens my app, but the number isn't coming up?

How do I get the number from the contact?

The Screen shot below will help in understanding what I am trying to achieve: I open the people app on my phone and then click contact name I get the below screen with a message icon beside the number. If I click the icon it opens my SMS app there it doesn't get the required number?

How do I get the number from the contact?

[image]

**update:**

I figured out it should the intent that I have call onCreate:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
```

action comes with "ACTION SENDTO"
But how to retrieve number?

Update 2:

I tried:

```
Uri number = intent.getData();       
Log.e("Number","from other App "+number);
```

Log shows in the following format:

```
smsto:%2B11233222321 (Phone number is stored in this format +11233222321)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in you sms app you should be able to recieve intent with ACTION_SENDTO and you can get the specified uri with intent.getData(). uri will be something like sms:23413451365 or smsto:23413451365 where you can parse the phone number

Comment: Thanks I tried like what you told me but couldn't get the result. Please check my question. I have updated with the issue.

Comment: So you have encoded uri. obtain specific part and decode it. Something like: Uri.decode(intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart())

Answer (score 0):

add permission your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

In you code:

```
    Cursor crs = null;
        try {
            crs = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
                    Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            int contact = crs.getColumnIndex(Phone._ID);
            int name = crs.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
            // this is what you need to get
            int number = crs.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
            crs.moveToFirst();
            do {
                String contText = crs.getString(contact);
                String nameText = crs.getString(name);
                // this is what you will get finally as the number
                String phoneText = crs.getString(number);
            } while (crs.moveToNext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (crs != null) {
                crs.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am not looking for this answer. Please read my question again. When I open the default contacts app and search for a contact number. I get the number, near the number I see a message icon when I click on the message icon - My SMS app open but without phone number? - I want to get the phone number too..

Comment: in your application's onActivityResult you can get number through this I wrote because I assumed you already know how to use onActivityResult.

Comment: Please check the question again!

Comment: downvoter, show reason. there is so much effort for answering and if it doesn't help the asker, does it have to be downvoted? This code is working for me. And my answer explains how to get contact number and use it in custom application.